# Custom views in Django admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am working on a Django project where I need to change almost half the features and the way Django admin manages the models. For e.g. I have to create an application and then create an administrator and assign that application such that this admin can manage only that particular application.  The administrators would be created by the global administrator of the project using the admin panel.

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can control who has access read/write/delete to what applications' data via the admin using [permissions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#id1).

Comment: Thanks for your reply Lakshman. But I far as I know Permissions are set per type of object and not per specific object instance. However, my requirement is to assign permissions per specific object instance.

Comment: Ankit: You can customize the queryset used on the admin. Here you go: http://github.com/leohemanth/new_pos/blob/old_repair/mksites/admin.py